# Xcode 9.3 keeps forgetting password for Xcode Server

Tags: xcode, xcode-server, xcode9.3

Everytime when I start Xcode 9.3 and go to the report navigator my Xcode Server is disconnected

[image: Disconnected Xcode Server in report navigator]

When I go to the accounts tab in settings it shows me an error.

[image: Disconnected Xcode Server in Xcode Settings]

When I enter the credentials it works.
But it seems like Xcode forgets the credentials every time I restart it.

I also went through this question ([xcode 9.3 session expires every time i close and re-open Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675844/xcode-9-3-session-expires-every-time-i-close-and-re-open-xcode)) because it could have been a problem with the keychain. It didn't help though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 9.3 session expires every time i close and re-open Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675844/xcode-9-3-session-expires-every-time-i-close-and-re-open-xcode)

Comment: @Gereon Although, your link is about Apple IDs and my problem is about the server in my local network i tried to go through the solutions because it could have been a problem with the keychain. Unfortunately it didn't help.